# Increasing Size for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I has installed Ubuntu in my windows laptop.I have installed in C drive.
I have allocated only 30GB hard disk space. But now i need to increase it.

I would like to move it to another Drive with More space. Is it possible ??
If possible without losing my data in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk partitioning tool in Ubuntu (usually GParted) is capable of resizing both Windows and Linux partitions.

You might need to boot from a USB pen or a CD, but once the OS is booted, you can run the parititoning tool to shrink the windows partition, and increase the size of the linux partition.

It is critical to back up data from both systems first as it is possible that things can go awry, resulting in data loss.

Moving the Ubuntu installation to another disk is more awkward, as you will have to adjust mount points, as well as your GRUB config.

In the past, I have tried migrating the OS, but now I favour a more simple approach.

First, take a full backup of your data (I have succesfully used Back In Time for this).

Second, wipe out your old Ubuntu partition, and recreate one for the new syste,

Thirdly, reinstall Ubuntu.

Finally, restore your backup.

Back In Time will keep your user data and packages stored, and it works on the file system level. It doesn't care where on the disk the partitions were, so long as you have enough space to carry out the restore.

There are ways to move the partitions without having to reinstall the OS, but I have had limited success using this approach with Ubuntu.