# Increasing available disk size in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a 250 GB SATA SSD. I was in a hurry while I was setting up the OS in this disk, so I selected Next in "Disk Partition" part without changing anything. I thought all of the disk will be used for Ubuntu, however I was wrong. Only 111 GB of the disk is splitted for Ubuntu, other part belongs to Windows which has been set up on my M2 SSD.

So, here are the disk properties:

```
== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 250GB
Firmware Version: SVT02B6Q
User Capacity:    250.059.350.016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x09fc), ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat May  6 20:17:57 2023 +03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Here is the usage:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           1,6G  2,6M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda4       111G   53G   53G  50% /
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs           7,9G   67M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

The output of fdisk -l :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      32768 249842520 249809753 119,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  249843712 250892287   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda4  250892288 488396799 237504512 113,3G Linux filesystem
```

In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/928733/increasing-size-for-ubuntu) answer, answer suggests to reboot from a USB. Is there another way to make Ubuntu use the whole space of this SSD, basically to increase the size?

Comment: I understand Windows to be on another disk and therefore no longer needed on the Ubuntu disk. You would need to delete the Microsoft partitions, move the EFI partition to the start of the drive and then move/expand the Ubuntu drive to the new free space. You should be able to do this from a Linux Live boot using gparted. Here is a guide that has a solution that may help you. There is a comment in the guide that says moving the root partition might mis-map the UUID. I have no guidance on this potential issue. BEFORE MAKING ANY CHANGES, BACKUP ANYTHING YOU DON'T WANT TO LOSE.

Comment: @Brian I think you could not embed the hyperlink to where it should be, there is no clickable link which should direct to the guide you mentioned in your comment .

Comment: Sorry, here it is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/430956/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-using-gparted

Comment: This is not easy. Consider reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch.  It is not really practical to attempt to fix this without USB booting or equivalent. Its conceivably possible but very, very hard, requiring multiple steps and advanced knowledge your question implies you dont have.  Ignoring the many and varied gotchas you theoretically could fiddle around and change the partitioning such that Linux is moved to the Windows partition and  then expanded.

Comment: A hack and partial workaround might be to reformat the Windows partition as a Linux/ext4 partitition, mount it and use symlinks or a union filesystem overlay to expand parts of the filesystem onto the new disk. This is a messy solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this answer, answer suggests to reboot from a USB. Is there another way to make Ubuntu use the whole space of this SSD, basically to increase the size?

There is, but it's really a bit fiddly, and you will most likely end up needing to boot from a live USB *anyway* in order to recover from some missed step (I might have forgotten some).

As you have enough space there, you *could*:

1. delete the Windows partition (and the useless "Microsoft reserved" one) and create whole new EFI and Linux partitions in the space (making a new 'sda1' to be the EFI System Partition, making it 512 MB similar to the existing one, instead of the 16 MB that the current 'sda1' has), formatting the former as FAT32 and the latter as Ext4;
2. copy the entire Ubuntu `/` filesystem's contents to the new 'sda2' using `cp -avx` or rsync, then do the same for the EFI partition's contents (from the existing 'sda3' to the new 'sda1');
3. reinstall the bootloader using `grub-install` (specifying the 'sda1' mountpoint as the EFI directory), as otherwise it probably won't be able to find its config;
4. edit the new bootloader's `grub.cfg` so that it refers to the UUID of the new 'sda2' partition instead of the old 'sda4' one, then do the same to the `etc/fstab` that's in the new 'sda2';
5. cross your fingers and reboot;
6. if the system was able to boot, delete the old sda3 & sda4 partitions, then use GParted from the *running* system to grow 'sda2' to the full disk size (expanding Ext4 on-the-fly is allowed, unlike moving or shrinking it).

So it's indeed doable (and sometimes useful – I've moved remote Linux installations from Ext4 to ZFS and then from ZFS to Btrfs this way) but I would not recommend it here (if you have to ask this question...), especially as the Ubuntu system sounds like it's still fresh and it'd be much less work to just reinstall it.